# ValueError: latex error converting to dvi

Tags: python, latex, tex

Запускаю скрипт.

```
class Name(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        z = Tex("e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)")
        self.add(z)
        self.wait(5)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
ValueError: latex error converting to dvi.
```

Использую `manim` (не `manimgl`).
Установлен `MiKTeX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я перерыл множество сайтов и перепробовал все что можно. Я множество раз переустанавливал `MiKTeX`. Я решил, что нужно скачать `LaTeX` вместо `MiKTeX` и в итоге скачал. Но все еще выдавало ошибку, но другую:

```
ValueError: Your installation does not support converting .dvi files to SVG.
Consider updating dvisvgm to at least version 2.4.
```

Но вдруг я подумал, что версия `manim` с `pip` была не той версии. Но она была как раз самой новой. Я решил удалить `manim` с `pip` и снова скачать его, но уже с использованием `Chocolatey`. После скачивания я перезагрузил компьютер и все заработало!

Везде писали, что дело в `TeX`, но в моем случае проблема была с `manim`.